# Do mutations in a fundamental structure of a virus [Omicron Variant] make it more transmissible?

Tags: microbiology, virology, mutations, coronavirus

I am not a microbiologist, nor a virologist so I had a question - in the new Omicron virus variant, a large number of mutations were reported for the protein spike.

From my naïve understanding, the spike is an integral part of how the virus replicates inside a host - thus, does it mean that changes in protein spike structure would lead to a more transmissible - therefore deadly variant?

And if so, won't the effect of vaccines reduce drastically since there's a fundamental change in the virus' structure which the immune system might not anticipate? Or the antibodies be able to handle?

Comment: Omicron as an escape variant might be a good example for  questioning  a rule that says "... more transmissible - therefore deadly variant". Any changes the success of which depend on immune escape  bear a chance that pathogenic factors are reduced and relinquished for the sake of transmissibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Converted from a comment.)

We have no idea at this point. Mutations are worrisome because they **could** indicate changes in transmissibility or virulence or capability for immune evasion, but it's almost impossible to predict.

### efficacy of vaccine/natural immunity

The easiest aspect to measure (approximately) will be immune evasion, by measuring the affinity of antibodies raised by existing vaccine to virus of the new strain in vitro ... transmission and virulence are much harder to quantify (or quantify proxies for) in the lab.

Antibody trials to evaluate efficacy are what a lot of immunologists will be spending their time doing over the next week or two: for example, from [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/nov/29/south-african-scientists-explore-vaccines-effectiveness-against-omicron)

> [Prof Penny Moore at the University of the Witwatersrand will engineer] “pseudoviruses” – harmless, non-replicating viruses used to model coronavirus variants ... to carry Omicron’s mutations. These will then be exposed to antibody-carrying blood plasma from vaccinated people and those who have recovered from Covid infection to see if they neutralise the virus.

> [Prof Alex Sigal from the African Health Research Institute in Durban] is growing batches of live Omicron from people who became infected in the recent surge in Gauteng in South Africa. Once he has enough to work with, the variant will be tested against blood plasma from vaccinated people and those with some natural immunity after a Covid infection.

### transmissibility

Again, it's hard to predict what will happen to transmissibility simply from knowing the genetic sequence. It is possible to do *in vitro* studies with cell lines to try to estimate changes in transmissibility, although these do not perfectly predict how much a real live infected person will transmit (for example, these tests are done *without* any involvement of the immune system). e.g.: Hou et al 2020, Plante et al. 2021.

### virulence

Virulence describes the severity of illness in a person infected with a given strain. This is probably the hardest of the three characteristics to measure in the lab; we may just have to wait until the omicron strain has spread and observe the fraction of cases that need to be hospitalized or sent to the ICU (although this still won't tell us what fraction of people who are infected have very mild or asymptomatic cases and are never even recorded as COVID cases ...)

---

Hou, Yixuan J., Shiho Chiba, Peter Halfmann, Camille Ehre, Makoto Kuroda, Kenneth H. Dinnon, Sarah R. Leist, et al. “SARS-CoV-2 D614G Variant Exhibits Efficient Replication Ex Vivo and Transmission in Vivo.” Science 370, no. 6523 (December 18, 2020): 1464–68. https://doi.org/10.1126/science.abe8499.

Plante, Jessica A., Yang Liu, Jianying Liu, Hongjie Xia, Bryan A. Johnson, Kumari G. Lokugamage, Xianwen Zhang, et al. “Spike Mutation D614G Alters SARS-CoV-2 Fitness.” Nature 592, no. 7852 (April 2021): 116–21. https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-020-2895-3.